# What is the meaning of this product notation?

Tags: differential-geometry, algebraic-topology, category-theory, operads

Let $X,Y$ be topological spaces, both of which admit an action by a group $G$. What is the definition of the space denoted by $ X \times_G Y $?

In particular, let $C_n(k)$ denote the space of ordered $k$-tuples of $n$-dimensional cubes in $I^n$ with disjoint interiors. This space admits an action by the symmetric group $\Sigma_k$ by permutation of the cubes. Similarly given a space $X$, the $k$-fold product $X^k$ admits an action by $\Sigma_k$ by permuting the terms. What is the definition of the space $C_n(k) \times_{\Sigma_k} X^k$?

Comment: It's a quotient determined by the orbits.

Comment: @Randall Thanks for the reply. I suspected as much. Is it simply the quotient $(X \times Y) / G$ where $G$ acts on $X \times Y$ by $(x,y)g =(xg,yg)$?

Comment: Not exactly! Uff, someone else will answer before me :-) now I can't

Comment: Also, depending on your situation, it could be homotopy-quotient.

Comment: @Randall Thank you for the reply! I had in in fact not come across the notion of a homotopy quotient before. I believe that is in fact what the notation is referencing.

Comment: $G$ must act on $X$ on the right and on $Y$ on the left. So if you have two right $G$-spaces you must use inversion to turn a right action into a left action.

Comment: @North:  I can't speak for everyone whose used that notation, but I have used it in several papers, amd always with a variation of the meaning you wrote in your comment.  The variations are merely which side the $g$ goes on and whether I put $g$ or $g^{-1}$, which all come down to whether I am using left actions or right actions.